# "user hasn't approved this consumer" After Refreshing Sandbox with Admin approved users are pre-authorized enabled

Tags: connected-apps

I have just refreshed a sandbox and updated the Consumer Key on a connected app but I keep getting `Error authenticating with JWT config due to: user hasn't approved this consumer`. `Admin approved users are pre-authorized` is selected with the System Admin profile. I've tried changing it to `All users may self-authorize` and back again but I can't get it to work.

This is working fine in production and in multiple sandboxes, including this one before I refreshed it. How can I get the user to approve the consumer?

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox refreshes cause a completely new and independent version of your connected apps from production to be created and installed in the refreshed sandbox.

You need to go through an OAuth flow that returns a refresh token (web server flow, user-agent flow) before you can use the JWT Bearer flow whenever you're using a new connected app for the first time (and it *is* a new connected app with its own consumer key and secret).

The easiest way I've found to do this is to use a tool like Postman to go through the web server (Authorization Code) flow. If you're not familiar with how to do that, I go into a little more detail on [a similar question from 2 weeks ago](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/374342/what-changes-need-to-happen-to-a-connected-app-after-a-sandbox-refresh/374346#374346)

Comment: Thanks I've tried your approach using postman but im getting the below error after I login to my sandbox

Authentication failed
Couldn't complete authentication. Check the Postman Console for more details.

"Error: grant type not supported"

Comment: Also why would I need to go through this process if Admin approved users are pre-authorized is already selected?

Comment: @jonny-harte Can't really help with the postman error other than to say "double check you've filled everything out correctly". As for why you need to go through the process, that's just what Salesforce dictates. Again, this is a _completely new connected app_ in your refreshed sandbox that hasn't been used before, ever. The way Salesforce implemented the JWT Bearer flow dictates that you _must_ go through another flow (one that can give you a refresh token) once per org before you can use the JWT Bearer flow in that org.